# Spring JPA Assosiation entity create the same record

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I'm setting Spring Boot Aplication
Trying to make make "add user menu", everytime I post JSON data like this ex:

MySQL always create new ADMIN record in `role_table`.

My intention is only create one single admin record in `role_table` for multiple user in `user_table`(one to manny)

So far I've tried to modify several Spring JPA Annotation different kind of fetch, association, and configuration.

So far the result on my MySql database table like this:

```
role_table.    user_table
id.   role.    id    username  role_id
1    Admin      1    Tony      1
2.   User       2.   Buddy.    2
3.   Guest.     3.   Liaska.   3
4.   Admin      4.   Roy.      5
5.   Admin.     5.   Subrey.   4
6.   User.      6.   Alhanus.  7
7.   Guest      7.   Rsidi.    6
```

I expected the result in my MySql table like this:

```
role_table.    user_table
id.   role.    id    username  role_id
1    Admin      1    Tony      1
2.   User       2.   Buddy.    2
3.   Guest.     3.   Liaska.   3
                4.   Roy.      1
                5.   Subrey.   3
                6.   Alhanus.  1
                7.   Rsidi.    1
```

Thanks to you all

Role class like this:

```
public class Role implements Serializable{


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name="id", length=8, unique = true)
private int id;

@Column(name = "role",nullable = false, unique = false)
private String role;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="role", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();}
```

User class like this:

```
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name="user_id", length=8, unique = true)
private int user_id;

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String password;



@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Role role;}
```

AdminController class like this:

```
public class AdminController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminController.class);


@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

 @Autowired
  private RoleRepository roleRepository;

 private Role role = new Role();

@Autowired
 private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
@PostMapping("/admin/add")
 public String addUserByAdmin(@RequestBody User user){

    String pwd = user.getPassword();

    String encryptedPwd = passwordEncoder.encode(pwd);

    user.setPassword(encryptedPwd);



    if(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername())==null){

        userRepository.save(user);

    } else {

         return "user already exist
    }
    return "user added successfully ... ";


}
```

Comment: How are you saving Role. In AdminController  I can see only a new Object of Role is created. Where is it linked with User? Can you please add that part of code

Comment: i just simply post JSON object with App called postman and spring handle everything, I dont create linked user thing, spring boot handle it automaticly, JSON data that I post looks like this  "username": "Frantu",
 "password": "Pshycho8k8ss",
 "role" : {"role":"ADMIN"}

Comment: Exactly, Since you are just passing role as ADMIN and no primary key. It is treated as a new record and you get multiple roles in DB.

Comment: I get it now... thx you all guys.   changing cascadeType.ALL to cascadeType.MERGE work...with JSON data like this User {id=0, username = Frantu, password= Pshycho8k8ss , role = {id=0, role=ADMIN }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the initialization your persistence of `role` object. Here you are getting user object in JSON as following :

```
 {"username": "Frantu", "password": "Pshycho8k8ss", "role" : {"role":"ADMIN"} }
```

which does not have id field initialized for role entity.

So your User object will be like

```
User {id=0, username = Frantu, password= Pshycho8k8ss , role = {id=0, role=ADMIN }
```

You are not passing `role.id` here So JPA will create a new record with new primary key for every new request.

To fix the issue, first, get `role` from DB if present using `role` attribute and set it to the User object.

```
Role dbRole = roleRepository.findByRole(user.getRole().getRole());
if(dbRole!=null){
     user.setRole(dbRole);
}

userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: User {id=0, username = Frantu, password= Pshycho8k8ss , role = {id=0, role=ADMIN } really work for me...with additional changing in cascadeType.ALL to cascadeType.MERGE...thx for your help.